# Creating FormData() in firebase-functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need to create FormData() to be able to hit Instagram oauth token endpoint. Apparently Instagram is very particular about this needing to be formatted exactly like a form.

Cloud Functions doesn't have FormData() constructor. I don't know of any other way to create form data for upload to a server.

I have tried simple-oauth2 as a solution but it does not appear to be uploading true form data because it doesn't work, it gets the same 400 error I've been getting with trying to use things like params etc.

TLDR: how do I *CREATE* form data inside firebase functions environment without access to FormData()?

bonus points: why doesn't firebase functions have access to FormData()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Cloud Functions and Firebase Functions you need to use [Form-Data library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data)

I did write test Function and deployed it successfully with the following code:

1. Include form-data in your [package.json dependencies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies), current version is 2.5.1:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "form-data": "2.5.1"
  }
```

2. Require new library and use it in your code:

```
var FormData = require('form-data');

var form = new FormData();
form.append('my_field', 'my value');
form.append('my_buffer', new Buffer(10));
form.append(....
```

Bonus: Functions are designed to be lightweight and have shortest startup time possible. Due to this they contain only selected core functionality. More can be added from external packages. You can check what is [included in Cloud Functions (and Firebase Functions)](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/nodejs-system-packages) in the documentation.